# Выполнение по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: c#

Есть часть кода:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int n = 5;                  // число вершин
            double R1 = 25, R2 = 50;   // радиусы
            double alpha = 30;        // поворот
            double x0 = 60, y0 = 60; // центр

            PointF[] points = new PointF[2 * n + 1];
            double a = alpha, da = Math.PI / n, l;
            for (int k = 0; k < 2 * n + 1; k++)
            {
                l = k % 2 == 0 ? R2 : R1;
                points[k] = new PointF((float)(x0 + l * Math.Cos(a)), (float)(y0 + l * Math.Sin(a)));
                a += da;
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points);
        }
```

Что необходимо сделать, что бы он выполнялся по нажатии кнопки на форме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

назначьте событие на кнопку, проще всего это кликнуть 2 раза по кнопке в визуальном редакторе формы, если вы работаете с WinForm. Далее уже перенести код в метод который срабатывает по клику кнопки.

Comment: Так уже пробовал. Если просто перенести текст компилятор ругается, что нужен `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)`, а в кнопке -- `button_build_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Используйте в событии кнопки: 

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            g.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points);
        }

Comment: Я что-то не так сделал? https://goo.gl/onUcfw + https://goo.gl/tKKQ5E

Comment: прошу прощение, я маленько ошибся. Вам нужно написать: g.DrawLine();

Comment: Всё равно ему что-то не нравится :( https://goo.gl/uF4o5p

Comment: @Дмитрий pictureBox1 это компонент с формы,

Comment: Который есть на форме. Но как я слышал в видео уроке, есть возможность рисовать прямо на форме. Так, по идее, проще.
Возможно ли в данном варианте сделать именно так?

Comment: Разобрался, рисует. Большое спасибо!